# Ordering of map and reduce tasks

Tags: mapreduce, task

Having job j consisting of "M" number of map tasks and "R" number of reduce tasks.

```
M(1) M(2)...... Map(m)
 Reduce(1) Reduce(2) ... Reduce(R)
```

How do you know the ordering between map and reduce tasks? We know that output of Map tasks will be input of Reduce tasks. But if I want to simulate the ordering how should I do it?
For example

`M1 M2 M3`

`R1 R2`

is it possible having output of "M1" and "M2" be input of "R1" and output of "M3" input of "R2"? In real case how is the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You order the mappers and reducers by:

- Configuring jobs with specific mappers and reducers, and
- Defining the flow of jobs

A job can have any number of mappers and reducers.  You can define the job dependencies explicitly with a script or oozie workflow or you can let your workflow manager (Azkaban, oozie, etc.) work out the dependencies based on which job's mappers use which jobs reducers' outputs.

Comment: Thanks,What do you mean define the flow of jobs?Also I think each job set of its map and reduce and it is Independent of other jobs. Am I wrong?

Comment: You have to describe the sequence of jobs.  You can do it explicitly in code or a script or you can have a workflow manager figure it out for you based on which jobs create and read from which files/folders. And yes, other than that, each job is independently configured and executed.